How to verify a contract on bscscan created in remix.ethereum.org?
I created a Token using the remix.ethereum.org platform, the Token has already been deployed, it is possible to buy, add liquidity, etc. However, the Token is not verified on bscscan. When I try to verify, I add all the files that I used to create it, which are:

bep-20.sol
Context.sol
draft-IERC6093.sol
ERC20.sol
IERC20.sol
IERC20Metadata.sol

The following error occurs:
* Found the following ContractName(s) in source code : Context.sol:Context, ERC20.sol:ERC20, IERC20.sol:IERC20, IERC20Metadata.sol:IERC20Metadata, bep-20.sol:Tardis, draft-IERC6093.sol:IERC1155Errors, draft-IERC6093.sol:IERC20Errors, draft-IERC6093.sol:IERC721Errors

* But we were unable to locate a matching bytecode (err_code_2)

* For troubleshooting, you can try compiling your source code with the Remix - Solidity IDE and check for exceptions

Bytecode (what we are looking for)
...64736f6c6343000818003300000000000000000000000000000000000000000052b7d2dcc80cd2e4000000

vs what we got -
...{ipfs}64736f6c6343000819003300000000000000000000000000000000000000000052b7d2dcc80cd2e4000000

Perhaps this error occurs because I only used one file to create the Token on remix.ethereum.org, namely, the bep-20.sol.
In this case, I imported the ERC20 from OpenZeppelin using the GitHub repository as a reference:
https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol
However, bscscan does not support this type of import, so I had to locally access all the necessary contracts from OpenZeppelin.
But i couldn't verify yet.
